# mapping of numeric array onto second numeric array

Tags: arrays, matlab, mapping

I'm writing, because I was wondering if you guys might have a suggestion
for the following "array mapping" problem in MATLAB

I have a time array covering, a year in steps of one minute (T1) and
another time array (T2) that is inhomogeneously distributed and not
(necessarily) overlapping with T1.
An example would be:

```
T1 = [1-Jan-2011 00:01:23, 1-Jan-2011 00:02:23.... end of year 2011]
T2 = [1-Jan-2011 00:04:12, 1-Jan-2011 03:014:54, ....]
```

T1 and T2 are actually in `datenum` format, but I wanted to give a clear example here.

The length of the two is not the same, (`length(T1) ~ 5*length(T2)`),
but I know that no two elements of T2 are within the same interval in
T1. I mean that an element of T2 will be always uniquely identified by
one of T1.

What I want to do is (efficiently=quickly) mapping T2 onto T1, so
that I have a set of indexes idx such that `T1(idx(n))` is the closest
point in time to `T2(n)`. I already have a routine doing it, but it's a
little slow.

Suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the result of `datenum` are simple numbers.

```
[~,idx1]=sort([T1+offset,T2]);
idx = find(idx1>length(T1));
idx = idx - (0:length(idx)-1);
```

If you leave out the `offset` (or use `0`),  this will give you for each element of `T2` the index of the smallest element if `T1` that is larger. To get to the one that is closest, add half the interval length in `T1` to `T1` (i.e. the `datenum` equivalent of half a minute).

[edit]
If `T1` does not consist of equidistant steps, one could try with a vector containing the middle of each interval in `T1` instead.

```
T1m = [(T1(1:end-1) + T1(2:end))/2];
[~,idx1]=sort([T1m,T2]);
idx = find(idx1>length(T1m)) - (0:length(T2)-1);
```

[/edit]

How this works:

We first sort the vector of all time points, then ignore the actual result (replace `~` by a variable name, e.g. `T` if you want to use it somehow). The second return value of `sort` is the index of each entry of the sorted array in the original array. We want to know where the ones from `T2` ended up, i.e. those that in the original, concatenated array `[T1 T2]` have an index larger than the number of values in `T1`, which is the `idx` from the second line. Now these indices refer to the elements of the combined array, which means relative to `T1` they are correct for the first element, off by one for the second (since the first element of `T2` was thrown in before), off by two for the third (since two elements of `T2` come before)..., which we correct in the third line.

You can combine the second and third line to `idx = find(idx1>length(T1)) - (0:length(T2)-1);`

Comment: Hello Arne, thanks a lot for your answer. 
As far as I can see (once I swap T2 and T1), it works, but it is not telling me if the nearest point is the one above or below.

For example for: T1 = [1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9];
T2 = [1.3 3.7 8.1];
I obtain idx = [2 4 8];

These correspond to the elements of T1 that are imediately greater than each element of T2, but I don't have the information about which element of T2 is nearest to each element of T1. Or not? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Riccardo Could it be that you ignored my ramblings regarding the offset? There was a mistake in my explanation that by using offset 0 you would get the lower limit: you actually get the upper. Sorry about that, fixed it above. Do note also that your `T1` does not contain equidistant steps (4 is missing), so the offset thing becomes more complicated.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to mention that is really fast!

Comment: ehm... yes, I sort of glided over your comment on the offset :)
Sorry... but it works nicely and indeed, my T1 can be considered containing equidistant steps. Great, you just considerably speeded up my code. Thanks so much. R